# Android - Fragment MyFragment not attached to an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, fragment

I'm seeing a crash that I am unable to reproduce myself. This crash happens in the splash screen of the app. **requireActivity()** is returning null.

I am using Navigation component. **MainActivity** is the first activity started and it's **startDestination** is the splash fragment.

Main activity is pretty much empty since navigation component handles the first fragment transaction.

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Here is my SplashScreenFragment:

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {

    private val isFirstLaunch get() = PreferenceHelper.getObject<Boolean>(PREF_FIRST_LAUNCH) ?: true
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSplashBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding =  FragmentSplashBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Show loading animation
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        Log.d("TAG", "isFirstLaunch: $isFirstLaunch")

        Handler().postDelayed({

            Log.d("TAG", "postDelayed finished")

            if (isFirstLaunch){
                navigateToA()
            } else {
                navigateToB()
            }
        }, DELAY_COUNT)
    }


    private fun navigateToA(){
        startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), ActivityA::class.java))
        requireActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
        requireActivity().finish()
    }

    private fun navigateToB(){
        startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), ActivityB::class.java))
        requireActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
        requireActivity().finish()
    }

    companion object {
        const val PREF_FIRST_LAUNCH = "PREF_FIRST_LAUNCH"
        const val DELAY_COUNT = 4000L
    }
}
```

I heavily logged the flow of trying to pin down the problem. This is one instance of the crash.

```
MainActivity : onCreate
SplashFragment : onAttach
SplashFragment : onViewCreated
MainActivity : onResume
SplashFragment : onResume
SplashFragment : isFirstLaunch: true
SplashFragment : onPause
MainActivity : onPause
SplashFragment : onDetach
MainActivity : onDestroy
MainActivity : onCreate
SplashFragment : onAttach
SplashFragment : onViewCreated
MainActivity : onResume
SplashFragment : onResume
SplashFragment : isFirstLaunch: true
SplashFragment : postDelayed finished
SplashFragment : Navigating to ActivtityA
CRASH
```

Am I missing something obvious that would cause this to happen?
Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SplashFragment not attached to an activity.
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:833)
   at com.package.SplashFragment.navigateToA(SplashFragment.java:80)
   at com.package.SplashFragment.access$navigateToB(SplashFragment.java:25)
   at com.package.SplashFragment$onResume$1.run(SplashFragment.java:54)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Can you paste in the error stacktrace?

Comment: @MariuszBrona I added the stacktrace, but I think I found the issue! Screen rotation was not disabled! I think that's what caused the crash. I'm going to test it out and post an answer in a few days when I confirm this is the problem.

Comment: Turns out that this was not the problem, still getting crashes, rotating the screen did output very similar logs though, back to trying to find the problem